# Layout becomes deformed when window is resized

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with my website. Whenever I try to re-size my browser window. All of my text, images, and the navigation bar, goes everywhere on the screen.

Here are some screenshots:

**Normal Website**
[image: http://s16.postimg.org/cwypfajad/normal_website.jpg]

**Deformed Website**
[image: http://s23.postimg.org/sq4mgdmnv/deformed_website.jpg]

And here is the code.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Photoshop Uploader </title>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <style>
        body { background-color: #6F6F6F; margin: auto; }
        h1 { font-family: Verdana; }
        img.headerImg { position: relative; padding-top: 8px; padding-left: 8px; float: left; }
        #headerText { padding-top: 18px; padding-left: 15px; float: left; font-family: Verdana; color: #102261; font-weight: bold; }
        h2.socialText { font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; font-family: Verdana; float: left; padding-top: 25px; padding-left: 250px; }
        img.socialBar { position: fixed; }
        #social img { margin-top: 10px; margin-right: 40px; position: fixed; }
        #social img.facebook { float: right; padding-top: 23px; padding-right: 15px; position: relative; }
        #social img.instagram { float: right; padding-top: 23px; padding-right: 15px; position: relative; }
        #social img.youtube { float: right; padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 15px; position: relative; }
        #social img.twitter { float: right; padding-top: 25px; padding-right: 15px; position: relative; }
        #navBar ul { list-style-type: none; padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px; overflow: hidden; }
        #navBar a:link, a:visited { text-align: center; display: block; width: 120px; text-decoration: none; color: white; font-weight: bolder; background-color: #102261; padding: 4px; }
        #navBar a:hover, a:active { background-color: #0A153F; }
        #navBar li { float: left; border-right: 5px solid #6F6F6F; font-family: Arial; }
        h3.loginText { font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; float: right; padding-top: 35px; }
        p.login { padding-left: 100px; }
        p.usr_pass_text { color: #102261; font-weight: bold; font-family: Verdana; }
        #loginReg { padding-left: 900px; }
        a.clickReg { padding-left: 62px; color: #102261; text-decoration: none; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Header image w/ text -->
    <img class="headerImg" src="images/photoshop_icon.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"/>
    <h1 id="headerText"> Photoshop Uploader </h1>
    <!-- Social Media -->
    <h2 class="socialText"> Follow Me On... </h2>
    <div id="social">
        <img src="images/social_bar.png" class="socialBar" width="400" height="100"/>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/hayes.derbyshire"><img class="facebook" src="images/facebook_logo.png" alt="Facebook" width="42" height="42"/></a>
        <a href="http://www.instagram.com/hayesderbs"><img class="instagram"  src="images/instagram_logo.png" alt="Instagram" width="42" height="42"/></a>
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/hiii582"><img class="youtube" src="images/youtube_logo.png" alt="YouTube" width="48" height="48"/></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/Derby_Corn"><img class="twitter" src="images/twitter_logo.png" alt="Twitter" width="42" height="42"/></a>
    </div>
    <h3 class="loginText">Log In</h3>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <div id="navBar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index_photoshop.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="registration.php">Registration</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="loginReg">
    <form action="index_photoshop.html" method="post">
        <p class="usr_pass_text"> Username: <input type="username" name="user"/></p>
        <p class="usr_pass_text"> Password: <input type="password" name="pass"/></p>
        <a class="clickReg" href="registration.php"> Click Here to Register </a>
        <p class="login"><input type="submit" value="Login" name="login"/></p>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your all of your content with a container div:

```
<div class="container">the rest of your html</div>
```

Then give it a width:

```
.container{
   width:1100px;
   margin: auto; // add this if you want to center your container
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't styled `div#social`. give it a fixed width large enough to contain the social media images.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make your site **responsive**?

In doing so, will showcase flexible images and good display.

1. Create an external style sheet

   - I tell you, designing your site will be much easier.
2. Make your site [responsive](http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrolldeck.js/decks/responsive/) using [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: Hey, this is my first web site so I don't know a whole lot about making it "responsive" except for adding java script and making it very user friendly. I am working on putting a registration form into my website now and doing a lot with mySQL and PhpMyAdmin which is extremely irritating to use and especially set up. I would actually love some help on making it embedded in my html with PHP and using java script and other languages like ajax. Thanks and it would be so greatly appreciated, and can some one fluently explain to me how domains work assuming I already know about mySQL and phpmyadmin.